# ActionLink in Partial when Partial is rendered in an area

Tags: model-view-controller, actionlink, areas

I use a partial to render a culture chooser control. The control is stored under ~/Views/Shared/Control.cshtml. There are three actionlinks in the control for three different languages.

```
@Html.ActionLink("English", "ChangeCulture", "Home",  new { lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)
```

I can use this control on the default page when the app starts in the browser but if I use the control from an area it accesses the wrong controller. Is it possible to tell the actionlink in the control to use the "default" HomeController?

Thanks for your help in advance and let me now if more details are needed.

Best regards,
Frank.

EDIT:

This is the part of the layout page where the culture chooser control gets rendered:

```
    <div id="login_details">
        <div class="username">@ViewRes.SharedStrings.User: @User.Identity.Name</div>
        @ViewRes.SharedStrings.ChangePassword
        @*@Html.Partial("CultureChooserUserControl")*@
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/CultureChooserUserControl.cshtml")
    </div>
```

I know the third parameter points to the controller, the problem is that there is a HomeController in the area as well. Can I tell the ActionLink which HomeController to use?

Comment: The 3rth parameter in your actionlink is the controller parameter, that should be enough. Can you show me the rendered link the browser shows?

Answer (score 0):

Rename one of the HomeControllers

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify the Area in the route parameters?

```
@Html.ActionLink("English", "ChangeCulture", "Home",  
   new {Area = string.Empty, lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)
```

I had a similar problem trying to show my menu from a controller in an area.

My menu is a partial view from a MenuController.

In my _Layout.cshtml I'm now rendering the menu like this

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Menu",new{Area = string.Empty})
```

My MenuController does this...

```
    // GET: /Menu/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new MenuViewModel();
        vm.IsLoggedIn = CurrentUser != null;
        ...
        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```